# SELECT all items with 2 different status such that I will select items with status a and status b

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

```
SELECT
    `itemmaster`.*
FROM
`sds`.`itemmaster`
    WHERE `item_stock_code` = (SELECT
    `item_stock_code`
FROM
    `sds`.`itemmaster`
WHERE (`item_stock_code` ='221F0009DN00H2A')) AND 
`item_stock_code` = (SELECT
    `item_stock_code`
FROM
    `sds`.`itemmaster`
WHERE (`item_stock_code` ='221F0010DN00H2A'));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You have attempted a query, which is good, but unfortunately it is not clear which column is the status.  Can you also include the table structure for `itemmaster` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, have you pasted query twice while editing or changed?

Comment: what I have formatted is :
SELECT itemmaster.*
FROM sds.itemmaster
WHERE item_stock_code =
    (SELECT item_stock_code
     FROM sds.itemmaster
     WHERE (item_stock_code ='221F0009DN00H2A'))
  AND item_stock_code =
    (SELECT item_stock_code
     FROM sds.itemmaster
     WHERE (item_stock_code ='221F0010DN00H2A'));

Comment: @JigarShah The query does not appear to be pasted twice.

Comment: Why are you using Sub-Query for same table when you know item_stock_code. You can use `WHERE item_stock_code IN ('221F0009DN00H2A','221F0010DN00H2A' )`

Comment: @Sujit thanks, im sorry im not that familiar with other sql functions

Comment: no worries .. :)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

For Codeigniter, You can use:

```
$this->db->where_in('your_column', array('status1','status2'));
```

See this CI Reference [Link:or_where_in](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::or_where_in)

In SQL:

```
"SELECT * from your_table Where your_column IN (".implode(',',$your_satus_array).")";
```